# Как убрать стандартный интерфейс окна в Python TK?

Tags: python, tkinter

Мне нужно убрать стандартный интерфейс окна windows,чтобы вместо него было просто окно программы и 2 мои кнопки(закрыть и свернуть).И еще есть кнопка внизу программы,она прямо на самом краю,нужно сделать отступ снизу.Как это сделать через tkinter в Python ?
Мой код

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x500+300+300".format(root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()))
root.title('FBot')
root.add_img = PhotoImage(file="add.gif")
Img2=PhotoImage(file='bg.gif')
background = Label(root, image=Img2)
background.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
root['bg'] = ("#53524e")
Img1=PhotoImage(file='start.gif')
root.quit = Button(root,image=Img1,width=200,height=50,padx='10',bg='#53524e',bd=0,command=root.destroy)
root.quit.pack(side="bottom")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.overrideredirect()
root.focus_set()
root.mainloop()
```

Пробовал через root.overrideredirect(1),но в таком случае я получаю просто окно,с которым ничего нельзя сделать,кроме как смотреть на него.

Answer (score 1):

У меня было такое:

```
rt = tk.Tk() # Run Tkinter
rt.title("RunTASCIIc-v.1.0.3")
rt.attributes('-fullscreen', True) # Run the window in full-screen mode
rt.bind("<Key>", key) # Bind the press of any key

color = random.choice(('red', 'green', 'blue', 'violet', 'white', 'yellow')) # Set random color
text = tk.Text(rt, font="Courier 20", bg="Black", fg=color) # Create text and text parameters
text.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
```

Только я уже не помню что именно сработало: `text.pack(expand=True, fill="both")` или `rt.attributes('-fullscreen', True)`